# How to deal with "coding style activism" on the site?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Sometimes I suspect that some members downvote posts on principle.

- Any time you mention `goto` in a positive way, you are bound to get downvotes
- Mentioning singleton in Java without calling it antipattern is asking for trouble (the same pattern is considered mainstream in Objective-C tag)
- Suggesting a Prolog solution that uses the `!` "cut" operator

There are probably similar "red flags" in other tags as well.

I do no think that this is a good behavior: there are situations when the techniques that are "[considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)" in general provide a nice, readable, and easy to understand alternative to other alternatives that stay away from them.

First of all, do you think that this kind of behavior exists on this site, or my suspicions are unfounded?

If you think that this behavior does exist, what do you think is the best way to react to it? I often give in to peer pressure, and delete my answer. Is this really the best thing to do?

Comment: If people believe that using these is inappropriate then it is their right to downvote as they see fit

Comment: And similar to SO, there are people that just downvote and don't even leave a comment =\

Comment: Also; -1 suggested using goto, singleton and Prolog (whats wrong with singletons?)

Comment: There will be people trigger happy with upvoting too. Though would have to personally ask everyone to know if both up/down maniac-voting  is balanced or not. Are these things accurate? ie Is using "singleton" in Java and not "antipattern" bad? Even if perhaps only in a certain circumstance? If so, then there'll be downvotes.

Comment: `Suggesting a Prolog solution that uses the ! "cut" operator` The first time I heard about this. `!` is very useful to optimize the code execution. I don't know why it is bad idea to use it...

Comment: See second bullet under Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194704/191410

Comment: Are you talking about questions or answers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I disagree, and I would actually downvote most (if not almost all) posts using `goto`, singletons or other such questionable features.

Caveat: of course some of these features – such as `goto` – have their use in certain situations (such as error handling in C) – but outside of these specific use-cases I feel that there is a good case to be made (and *has* been made repeatedly) that the downsides outweigh the advantages so substantially that enforcing a simple rule (“don’t use”) consistently is superior to having lots of exceptions.

This is particularly true when used in example code on a site such as this, where the code should be, well, *exemplary*. I don’t consider that political activism, except maybe insofar as that I strive to keep (code) explanations on Stack Overflow as clean as possible.

Of course I would not downvote a valid use of any such feature, but what you consider valid may differ from what I consider valid.

That said, the question you linked to is different (and I disagree here with Jarrod, apparently): you’re not even using a singleton, you just always happen to return the same, `static` object. Despite your mention of it in the answer, this has almost *nothing* to do with the singleton, and potential lifetime concerns notwithstanding, I don’t see anything wrong with that code. If somebody downvoted that answer just because it contained the word “singleton” then they aren’t being over-zealous, they’re clueless.

Comment: Do you take into account the requirements stated in the question? I often see answers that recommend bad and sometimes downright terrible practices, but as it turns out, the OP has tied hands and has to be limited to a certain solution (due to existing design / architecture, pointy-haired boss, etc). So I hope you don't blindly down-vote any `goto` answer fi the context of the question states "I must use `goto` because <x>..."

Comment: @Aaron Well to be honest, 99% of these “I must use X because Y” are horse manure. Case in point, I cannot at the moment think of a valid technical reason for having to use `goto` rather than the “proper” solution in a given context. I also dislike answers that give the OP a quick&dirty fix rather than addressing the OP’s underlying problem, and I would usually downvote such answers anyway – because they are *not helpful* in the long run, and might actually be actively harmful.

Comment: I used `goto` as an example because it was already mentioned; I have no knowledge of it to be quite honest. I vehemently disagree with your blanket statement that 99% of these things are horse manure, and I think that's just a bad attitude to have. There are all kinds of constraints that prevent an OP from being able to use the best practices available, for example in SQL Server some people are stuck  with older versions of the platform that don't support the modern way to do things, and this is a budgetary constraint, not "horse manure."

Comment: I often answer the OP's question taking the OP's constraints in mind, so here's how to do it using `<x>`, but usually also mention that if they didn't have those limitations, the better way to do it is `<y>`. I hope you don't down-vote any of my answers that do that, because not only are they helpful to the OP (who, again, has very real, and not "horse manure" constraints), but they're also useful to future readers with the same limitations, or users on newer versions who don't know that the newer functionality is, in fact, better.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "99% of these 'I must use X because Y' are horse manure". I disagree strongly. You ALWAYS have to consider their personal scenario as there are so many possible reasons they have to do it that way. Sometimes it's inability to learn, or no time as they desperately need their script to "just work" and earn money to pay rent/food/wages. On a site such as this the "answers" should be exemplary too, and the "bad" way (as you put it) is going to be the answer to the question. It's better to answer directly, and then "suggest" to them "here's a better method, if you're interested"

Comment: -1 because this answer contains the word `goto`.  tl;dr for the rest of it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Of course I wouldn’t downvote that. But again, your constraints are *valid* technical reasons.  But OP explicitly mentioned, for instance, that answers which use a singleton *without mentioning* that it’s generally considered an antipattern get downvoted. Gee, I wonder why.

Comment: @James Well then, give me concrete examples. I am more than willing to change my point of view, but I require data, not mere hand-waving. But yeah, “inability to learn” doesn’t sound like a great reason, to be honest (and “no time” as well, to a lesser extent: if you cannot spend time learning an elementary tool, please don’t waste *my* time).

Comment: It's that precious "almost" that makes all the difference between downvoting blindly and downvoting after giving a technique a consideration in the context of a given question. It's examples like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18507973/335858) that I am talking about, when 30 people downvote one of a few legitimate uses of `goto` simply because it contains the keyword "goto".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The people in the comments have actually given good reasons for disagreeing with this use of `goto`. The `goto` is certainly clearer than OP’s other solutions but that’s a false dichotomy.

Answer (score 28):

I have no doubt that this happens, but isn't it what downvotes are for? If someone thinks a piece of code is bad form, it's their right to downvote it. If it really is good code, most of the time more users who really know the language will upvote it.

[image]

Or maybe everyone on SO is just a raptor.

Comment: Why can't it be both? ;)

Comment: Didn't the raptor fail to arrive a few years ago?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "everyone", but it looks like the number of raptors here greatly exceeds the number of raptors that come and get programmers in real life ;-)

Answer (score 13):

You may be right, of course there may also be down-votes on principle that involve the color of someone's hair or the fact they have a z in their username or they remembered the OP from some argument they had with them a year ago.

There's not really anything you can do about *why* someone down-votes, and in most cases you won't be able to make any assumptions about why they down-voted, unless they're brave enough to comment (I've stopped doing so because of the vengeful behavior that often ensues).

I have, on a couple of occasions, deleted answers that had inexplicable down-votes; in the long run, though, a good answer will out-score any mis-applied down-votes ([Example: +245, -2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212)), so who cares?

Comment: Those sorts of vote things happen all the time. My 3d highest upvoted answer is +17, -3. +1

Comment: I do not mean examples like yours, where +245/-2 shows some silly downvotes that are left without an explanation. I mean things like [+226, -30](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18507973/335858), where thirty downvotes were given to an answer showcasing one of a few places where `goto` can be used without a fear of raptors.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and I'm suggesting there's not really anything you can do about that. Some people are just going to down-vote blindly or for reasons you may not be able to determine or predict.

Answer (score 7):

### You can reverse this question and ask:

> *Why do so many fundamentally flawed and wrong answers promoting bad
> practices, naive knowledge and just plain ignorance get up voted by so
> many people?*

In the specific [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706817/return-same-instance-of-an-object-each-time/18706865#18706865) that this person is mentioning, if you review the actual code implementations of the downvoted answers, they are all seriously incorrect in some fashion, most of them multiple ways.

They all promote terrible practices, outdated idioms from the late '90s that are repeated over and over again by people that don't know any better.

Comment: "all seriously incorrect..."  *All*?  Got links?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18704313/177800) is a perfect example of something that needs to be downvoted into oblivion!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Actually, the owner deleted it, so there is not much of a problem and comments seem to be working as intended

Comment: @minitech that is my point, I downvote everything I see that is wrong or misleading someone that doesn't know better and leave a comment on why the answer should be ignored. Sometimes people delete their mistakes, less likely they actually fix their answers, but sometimes they just get upvoted like crazy or worse even accepted as correct. I guess I would be considered a *downvoting activist*, I have spent a major portion of my earned rep downvoting instead of hoarding the points. I figure that is what they were intended for.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Yes, great. If people upvote a bad answer, there’s not much more you can do than vote and leave a polite comment describing why it’s wrong or bad practice. It doesn’t happen *that* often. When it does, it’s annoying, but you have to move on… (*cough* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements/9815010#9815010 *cough*)

Comment: @minitech wow that is a whole lot of ignorance showing there! then again [this is the internet we are talking about](http://xkcd.com/386/)!

Comment: I find that phrases such as "all seriously incorrect in some fashion", "terrible practices", and "outdated idioms" all lack specifics. What makes a new flashy idiom from early teens "better" than a tried and tested idiom from late nineties? It is impossible to judge any of that without knowing the context in which a technique is applied. That's why I'm perplexed when I see an answer mentioning a singleton by name being downvoted twice in thirty seconds or less. This can be done only "on the policy that singleton is bad", which is a polite way of saying "without thinking".

Comment: How about that particular implementation was so fundamentally flawed as to not be salvageable by the author because they obviously didn't understand how to do it correctly or they would have posted a correct implementation, so they did the next best thing they just deleted it; which is the goal of the downvote system, better quality. *It doesn't take a seasoned developer to more than 3 seconds to know bad code when they see it.*